# Add class to matching element without other specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom-manipulation

Whenever a user clicks on the `body` I would like to add a class to a certain element, as long as that element doesn't have a specific class. The issue is, I re-use this element and some of these elements will have that specific class I mentioned and other will not. If one element has this class, with my current code, no element will have new class added.

[Here is a fiddle showing the behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/7L3ub1sp/).

Example:

```js
$('body').on('click', function(){
    if ($('.box').hasClass('red') && !$('.box').hasClass('stay-red')) {
        $('.box').addClass('blue');
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
}
.box {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box red stay-red"></div>
<div class="box red"></div>
```

Comment: use `.each` method as `$('.box')` return array not single element

Comment: suppose it's worth to remove .red class on.blue )

Comment: but if you are not doing much DOM manipulation other than class based selection then go for direct css selectors/filter given in below answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){

$('body').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('red') && !$(this).hasClass('stay-red')) {
          $(this).addClass('blue');
        }
    })
    
    
});
  
})
```

```css
html, body {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="box red stay-red"></div>
<div class="box red"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.box.red:not(.stay-red)').addClass('blue');
```

Is that what you want?

> :not() Selector https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

https://jsfiddle.net/7L3ub1sp/

Comment: You meant `$('.red:not(.stay-red)')`

Comment: Missing one part, the red class.  `.box.red:not...`

Comment: Then $('.box.red:not(.stay-red)')

Answer (score 2):

It will be a lot easier with `filter`, and will avoid your problem:

```js
$('body').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').filter('.red:not(.stay-red)').addClass('blue');
});
```

```css
html, body {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="box red stay-red"></div>
<div class="box red"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('body').on('click', function(){ 
    $('.box.red:not(.stay-red)').addClass('blue');
});
```

Or loop through all of them with each:

```
$('body').on('click', function(){

    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('red') && !$(this).hasClass('stay-red')) {
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid adding the new class to all elements if one of them has the other class, you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (or [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)):

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
if(![].some.call(els, function(el) {
  return el.classList.contains('stay-red');
}) [].forEach.call(els, function(el) {
  return el.classList.add('blue');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the body onclick you need:

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
     $('.box.red:not(.stay-red)').removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
});
```

You also need to remove the class .red, even if in this precise case it works because the class .blue is defined after the class .red in the CSS